# Powershell - ext File parse

Tags: xml, powershell

I know powershell (enough to get my by); however, i have ran into an issue in which i cant even find the answer on google..

I have this test.audit file (for example) that contains

```
#####################################
# test here blah blah
# text
# 1.23 
# sample
#####################################

    <check_type>
    # 1.2
    <custom_item>     
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.1 text blah blah"
    </custom_item>      
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.2 other text blah blah"
    solution              : "Set the max_log_file data and equal <mb>"
    </custom_item>  
    # 1.4    
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.1 more text blah blah"
    </custom_item>      
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.3 text blah blah"
    </custom_item>       
    </check_type>
```

Using that test.audit file.. I am trying to delete the entire "custom_item" string that contains a description of "8.1.1.1".

So the new file would look like

```
#####################################
# test here blah blah
# text
# 1.23 
# sample
#####################################

    <check_type>
    # 1.2     
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.2 other text blah blah"
    solution              : "Set the max_log_file data and equal <mb>"
    </custom_item>  
    # 1.4         
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.3 text blah blah"
    </custom_item>       
    </check_type>
```

I had someone help me however they tried to use the "XML" technique through powershell..

however, this will not work for several reason.. 
it contains a "#"
and it also has "" inside it which throws an error.

There was also one more solution

```
#$text = gc c:\temp\test.audit | Out-String

$text = @'
<check_type>
<custom_item>     
    system                 : "Linux"
    type                     : "CHECK"
    description           : "8.1.1.1 text blah blah"
</custom_item>      
<custom_item>       
    system                 : "Linux"
    type                     : "CHECK"
    description           : "8.1.1.2 other text blah blah"
</custom_item>      
<custom_item>       
    system                 : "Linux"
    type                     : "CHECK"
    description           : "8.1.1.1 more text blah blah"
</custom_item>      
<custom_item>       
    system                 : "Linux"
    type                     : "CHECK"
    description           : "8.1.1.3 text blah blah"
</custom_item>       
</check_type>
'@

[string]$text = $text -replace '<custom_item>', '=' -split '=' | ? {$_ -notmatch '8.1.1.1'}

$text = $text.Split("`n") | % {if ($_ -match '^\s+$') {'    <custom_item>'} else {$_}}

$text #| out-file c:\temp\test.audit
```

however this outputs the document to be very messy.. not line for line like it was

If someone could assist that would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegEx match and replace to clear this up. Check out [this](https://regex101.com/r/jG7lB1/1) explaination on RegEx101 if you want to see how the following works. It does output exactly what you are requesting I'm pretty sure.

```
$text = @'
#####################################
# test here blah blah
# text
# 1.23 
# sample
#####################################

    <check_type>
    # 1.2
    <custom_item>     
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.1 text blah blah"
    </custom_item>      
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.2 other text blah blah"
    solution              : "Set the max_log_file data and equal <mb>"
    </custom_item>  
    # 1.4    
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.1 more text blah blah"
    </custom_item>      
    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.3 text blah blah"
    </custom_item>       
    </check_type>
'@

$text -replace "(?s)[\r\n]*<custom_item>[^\/]*?8\.1\.1\.1.*?<\/custom_item>"
```

Since you can not use `-Raw` (meaning you have v2 of PowerShell most likely), you can do this:

```
$text = (Get-Content "\the\path\here") -join "`r`n"
$text -replace "(?s)[\r\n]*<custom_item>[^\/]*?8\.1\.1\.1.*?<\/custom_item>" | Out-File "\the\path\here"
```

When I ran that on my machine it provided this output (almost exactly what you asked for):

```
#####################################
# test here blah blah
# text
# 1.23 
# sample
#####################################

    <check_type>
    # 1.2

    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.2 other text blah blah"
    solution              : "Set the max_log_file data and equal <mb>"
    </custom_item>  
    # 1.4    

    <custom_item>       
        system                 : "Linux"
        type                     : "CHECK"
        description           : "8.1.1.3 text blah blah"
    </custom_item>       
    </check_type>
```

Comment: I did a what you said; however, it did not work... I did the following:
`$text = get-content "\the\path\here" | out-string
$text -replace "(?s)[\r\n]*<custom_item>[^\/]*?8\.1\.1\.1.*?<\/custom_item>"
$text | out-file "\the\path\here"`

Comment: Use `$text = (Get-Content "\the\path\here" -Raw) -replace "(?s)[\r\n]*<custom_item>[^\/]*?8\.1\.1\.1.*?<\/custom_item>"` instead

Comment: I get an error that "a parameter -raw cannot be found".. I tried removing it.. then it makes it into a mess of a document with 8.1.1.1 still in there

Comment: i think -raw does the same thing as `(Get-Content "\the\path\here" | Out-String)`

Comment: @AnthonyStringer It does not do the same thing. Out-String creates an array of strings, one for each line. `-Raw` creates a multi-line string. I will update my answer shortly to address older versions of PowerShell that do not accept `-Raw`

Comment: I appreciate all your help; however, your solution still does not work.

You are using the wrong version of text.. If you see my original question it contains a few xml comments as well as other text inside it

Comment: The code I gave provides almost exactly what you said your desired output should be except that it has a blank line after the commented out lines.